# Can't view JSON in RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, json, xml, rest

Have created a very simple REST web service in netbeans which simply views a database. The records of a table can be viewed in either XML or JSON when deployed and run in chrome. The records display fine in XML but when the XML option is removed and it has to return JSON I get a Internal Server 500 error with the root cause:

Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You should provide the complete stacktrace to this exception.